# How to use getpass library in python

Tags: python, getpass

I'm trying to use getpass library in python but I can't.
Can somebody help me to use it in vscode?

I tried:

```
Getpass import as input
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct Python syntax for importing the getpass module:

```
import getpass
```

We don't need to import the input function from a module because it is a built-in function in Python 3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `input` name in the `getpass` library; you can find the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

This is an example of usage:

```py
import getpass

user = input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
# do something with these credentials
```